# making a thread using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i want my bot to make a thread after someones used a suggestion  command so people can discuss it.

this is what i've got. i got no errors but it doesn't create a thread, everything else works.

````
@bot.tree.command(name="suggestion", description="Sends a suggestion to our suggestion channel!")
async def _suggestion(interaction, suggestion:str):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1059976520376012811)
    suggestEmbed = discord.Embed(color=0xFF5349)
    suggestEmbed.set_author(name=f'New suggestion by {interaction.user}', icon_url = f'{interaction.user.avatar}')
    suggestEmbed.add_field(name='The suggestion is:', value=f'{suggestion}')

    message = await channel.send(embed=suggestEmbed)
  
    await message.add_reaction(':white_check_mark:')
    await message.add_reaction(':x:')

    channel = bot.get_channel(int(1059976520376012811))
    thread = await channel.create_thread(
    name=f"{interaction.user}'s Suggestion Discussion")

    await thread.send(f"Discuss {interaction.user}'s suggestion!")
  
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Successful!", color=0x23B425)
    embed.add_field(name="This command was successful.", value="Your suggestion was successfully posted in #suggestions", inline=False)

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 0):

````
@bot.tree.command(name="suggestion", description="Sends a suggestion to our suggestion channel!")
async def _suggestion(interaction, suggestion:str):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1059976520376012811)
    suggestEmbed = discord.Embed(color=0xFF5349)
    suggestEmbed.set_author(name=f'New suggestion by {interaction.user}', icon_url = f'{interaction.user.avatar}')
    suggestEmbed.add_field(name='The suggestion is:', value=f'{suggestion}')

    message = await channel.send(embed=suggestEmbed)
  
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')

    channel = bot.get_channel(int(1059976520376012811))
    thread = await message.create_thread(
    name=f"{suggestion} Discussion",
    reason="Suggestion")

    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Discuss {interaction.user}'s suggestion!", color=0xFF5349)
    embed.add_field(name="Like, dislike or want to add onto someones suggestion?", value="Do that here! In this thread, you can discuss what you like, dislike or something smiliar you'd like to see!", inline=False)
    embed.set_author(name = f'{interaction.user}', icon_url = interaction.user.avatar)
  
    await thread.send(embed=embed)
  
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Successful!", color=0x23B425)
    embed.add_field(name="This command was successful.", value="Your suggestion was successfully posted in <#1059976520376012811>", inline=False)

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).